# How to get the selected item as String in a Blackberry AutoCompleteField?

Tags: blackberry

How to get the selected Item as string when using a Blackberry  AutoComplete Field. I am able to get the selected index currently. I am Overriding the onSelect method in the AutoCompleteField class as explained at

[Autocomplete Class Reference API JDE 5.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/AutoCompleteField.html#onSelect%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29)

### Code Snippet below -

```
AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList)
{
     public void onSelect(Object selection, int SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK) {
         ListField _list = getListField();
         if (_list.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
             Dialog.alert("You selected: "+_list.getSelectedIndex());
             // get text selected by user and do something...
         }
     }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of AutoCompleteField#onSelect(Object, int) sets the text of the AutoCompleteField object's AutoCompleteFieldEditField to the select parameter.  So you could query for the String that way.  Here's a snippet of what I mean:

```
AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList)
{
     public void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {
         super.onSelect(selection, type);
         if(selection != null) {
             String selectionAsString = getEditField().getText();
             // Do whatever else you need to do with the String.
         }
     }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  /*  
onSelect

    protected void onSelect(Object selection,
                            int type)

    Parameters:
    *selection - The selected item*
    type - The method of selection. This will be one of SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK SELECT_TRACKBALL_CLICK SELECT_ENTER

*/

BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        String[] days = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                         "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
        filterList.addDataSet(1,days,"days",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);

        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList){
            protected void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {
                BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) selection;
                Dialog.alert("You selected: "+ result._object);
                super.onSelect(selection, type);
            }
        };
        add(autoCompleteField);
```

Comment: what should I be using to get the selected item as string> If you see the Dialog.alert("You selected: "+_list.getSelectedIndex());
We get the index of the selected item. what I want to know is how to get the selected item as string.