# How to get input text into the listfield of autocompletefield in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to make something like the contact selection in OS 5.0 while composing message

For that I have made an autocompletefield with contacts as datasource. Now I want to add the user input, that is what he types into the drop down list which appears in autocompletefield so that if the contact is not available in the phonebook he can use the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link: [How to get the selected item as String in a Blackberry AutoCompleteField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278352/how-to-get-the-selected-item-as-string-in-a-blackberry-autocompletefield)

> public void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {

```
     super.onSelect(selection, type);
     if(selection != null) {
         String selectionAsString = getEditField().getText();
         // Do whatever else you need to do with the String.
     }
 }
```